# Der Unterschied zwischen "sollen" und Konjunktiv

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, subjunctive, modal-verb

Um mein Deutsch zu verbessern, höre ich an die langsam gesprochene Nachrichten von der Deutschen Welle. Dort gab es diesen Satz:

> Der Schweizer Geheimdienst soll in die Finanzverwaltung von Nordrhein-Westfalen einen Spitzel eingeschleust haben.

*Soll eingeschleust haben* drückt die Unsicherheit dieser Aussage aus. Ich habe meinen einzigen deutschen Freund gefragt, ob man hier Konjunktiv nicht benutzen kann (*habe eingeschleust* oder *hätte eingeschleust*). Er antwortete, dass, obwohl beide Unsicherheit ausdrücken, es einen feinen Unterschied dazwischen sei, aber er könne es mir nicht erklären.

Kann jemand erklären, wann man *sollen* und Konjunktiv benutzen würde?

---

English version in case my German is worse than I hoped:

In order to improve my German, I listen to the *langsam gesprochene Nachrichten* (slowly spoken news) from Deutsche Welle. There was this sentence:

> Der Schweizer Geheimdienst soll in die Finanzverwaltung von Nordrhein-Westfalen einen Spitzel eingeschleust haben.

*Soll eingeschleust haben* here expresses the uncertainty about the statement. I asked my only German friend, whether one could use the subjunctive mood here (*habe eingeschleust* or *hätte eingeschleust*). He answered that although both express uncertainty, there was a subtle difference, but he couldn’t explain it.

Could anybody clarify when one would use *sollen* and the subjunctive mood?

Comment: *Er antwortete, dass, […] beide Unsicherheit ausdrücken* – Auch wenn Deutschlehrer und sogar Grammatikbücher das häufiger behaupten, ist das Quatsch. Der Konjunktiv II drückt Unmöglichkeit aus; der Konjunktiv I indirekte Rede. Unsicherheit wird im Deutschen mit Adverbien wie *vielleicht,* Modalverben wie *sollen* oder Phrasen wie *ich vermute* ausgedrückt. Der Konjunktiv ist hierzu nicht in der Lage.

Comment: Wikipedia: _For example,_ Er sagte, er sei ein erfahrener Arzt _is a neutral representation of what was said and makes no claim as to whether the speaker thinks the reported statement is true or not (...) If a writer doubts the reported statement, Konjunktiv II can be used instead:_ Er sagte, er wäre ein erfahrener Arzt. — Ist das falsch? Ich dachte, Konjunktiv ein Distanz zur Aussage herstellt und daher drückt Unsicherheit aus.

Comment: *Ist das falsch?* – Nein (wobei ich *doubts* etwas schwach finde und eher *considers false* sagen würde). Aber Zweifel/doubts sind eben nicht dasselbe wie Unsicherheit/uncertainty, sondern höchstens eine Untermenge. Unsicherheit ist neutral; Zweifel haben eine negative Tendenz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dar Hauptunterschied zwischen

> Der Schweizer Geheimdienst soll einen Spitzel eingeschleust haben ...

und den anderen Formen der indirekten Rede ist, dass mit Absicht *keine Quelle* angegeben ist. Diese Form wird verwendet, wenn es sich bei der Nachricht um ein Gerücht (Hörensagen) handelt, die Quelle anonym bleiben will/muß oder der Sprecher keinerlei Aussage über die vermutete Glaubwürdigkeit der Quelle machen will.

Das bedeutet nicht automatisch, dass der Wahrheitsgehalt der Aussage niedriger ist als bei der indirekten Rede (dort wird ja auch keine Aussage über den Wahrheitsgehalt gemacht). Da allerdings nicht angegeben wird, wer für diese Aussage steht, ist sie auch i.A. für niemanden nachprüfbar.

Bei der indirekten Rede muß immer angegeben sein, *wer* etwas gesagt hat - Das ist bei dieser Form nicht notwendig. Selbst wenn gesagt wird

> Laut der Finanzverwaltung soll der Schweizer Geheimdienst ...

wird kein offizieller Sprecher oder eine bestimmte Person genannt. Man kann diese Form verwenden, wenn man z.B. eine Quelle in der Finanzverwaltung hat, die man nicht preisgeben will. Man könnte denselben Sachverhalt auch (ungeschickt) ausdrücken als

> Jemand (den wir nicht nennen wollen oder können) in der Finanzverwaltung hat uns gesagt, der Schweizer Geheimdienst habe ...

Ähnliche Formen mit Modalverben werden oft in Gerichtsverhandlungen verwendet:

> Der Zeuge *will gesehen haben* wie der Täter die Tat beging

Wir erwähnen nur die Tatsache, was der Zeuge erwähnt hat und distanzieren uns von irgendeiner Aussage über die vermutete Glaubwürdigkeit.

> Der Zeuge *soll gesehen haben* wie der Täter die Tat beging

Wir erwähnen, das wir *von einem Dritten* erfahren haben, was der Zeuge wohl gesehen hat - Hörensagen. Auch hier keinerlei Aussage über die vermutete Glaubwürdigkeit.

Die Tatsache, dass der Sprecher sich allerdings von irgendeiner Aussage über die Glaubwürdigkeit der Quelle enthält, spricht u.U. schon für sich. Es kann daher u.U. auch gedeutet werden als "wir sind uns nicht sicher, ob wir das glauben sollen".

Comment: _Laut der Finanzverwaltung soll der Schweizer Geheimdienst ..._ — ist hier der Finanzverwaltung nicht die Quelle? Könnten wir hier die indirekte Rede nicht benutzen? Oder muss die Quelle immer eine Person sein?

Comment: Wenn *die Finanzverwaltung* irgendetwas sagt, dann gibt es einen offiziellen Sprecher oder einen Namen dazu. Damit kann man eine indirekte Rede verwenden. *Laut ... soll ...* kann durchaus auch nur bedeuten, dass es dort ein Gerücht gibt, das besagt, dass...

Answer (score 1):

> Der Schweizer Geheimdienst soll in die Finanzverwaltung von Nordrhein-Westfalen einen Spitzel eingeschleust haben.

Dieser Satz steht im Indikativ, weil er keine indirekte Rede darstellt, sondern eine Aussage, deren Wahrheitsgehalt der Berichterstatter nicht bewerten will.

Konjunktiv I ist hingegen immer indirekte Rede:

> *Die Polizei teilte mit,* der Schweizer Geheimdienst **habe** in die Finanzverwaltung von Nordrhein-Westfalen einen Spitzel **eingeschleust**.

Die Polizei ist sich in diesem Fall ihrer Sache sicher, und der Berichterstatter zieht das auch nicht in Zweifel.

Man könnte Konjunktiv II verwenden:

> *Die Polizei teilte mit,* der Schweizer Geheimdienst **hätte** in die Finanzverwaltung von Nordrhein-Westfalen einen Spitzel **eingeschleust**.

In diesem Fall klingt es jedoch so, als ziehe der Berichterstatter die Aussage der Polizei in Zweifel. Das ist die Nebenwirkung des Konjunktiv II.

Die tatsächlich vom Berichterstatter verwendete Konstruktion mit *soll* ist also absichtlich gewählt, um keine Aussage zum Wahrheitsgehalt der Mitteilung der Polizei zu treffen.